# Including legend with reference magnitude in a VectorPlot

Tags: plotting, legending, vector

I'd like to plot a vector field with a legend for the magnitude of a reference vector. I have read all the document of `VectorPlot` and found only `PlotLegends` is possible for this purpose. But I cannot come up with a solution. I also found a similar question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110516/vector-plot-with-magnitude-as-legend) without the desired solution. So I post a minimal question here. Note that I do not want to visualize the magnitudes with colors, so please do not waste your time.

**Question:** How can I plot a vector field with a reference legend showing the reference magnitude? For example, in this figure, the arrow length of the legend should be related to that of the vector field to indicate a reference length.

```
VectorPlot[{y, -x}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotLegends -> {"Ref. vector"}]
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by reference length? if you run `InputForm[VectorPlot[{y, -x}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotLegends -> {"Ref. vector"}]]` you will see that `PlotLegend` is formed from an arrow of unit length `Arrow[{{0, 0.5}, {1, 0.5}}]` placed `After`. So, this unit arrow has reference length, in some sense at least.

Comment: @Alx reference length means a 'ruler' with a given length, which can be used to determine/estimate the magnitudes of other vectors in the field. Considering point (x=-3, y=3) gives vector (3,3) which has a length of about 4.243. So it is expected that the length of this arrow there has a length of 4.243 times of the reference length, i.e. the length of the legend.

Comment: What about `VectorColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic`?

Comment: Maximal arrow length is `Maximize[{Norm[{y, -x}], -3 <= x <= 3 && -3 <= y <= 3}, {x, 
   y}] // First = 3 Sqrt[2]`. Lengths of vectors are scaled to the diagonal of the plot range, in your case this is `6*Sqrt[2]`. So, using `VectorScale` option and `Legended`: `Legended[VectorPlot[{y, -x}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, VectorScale -> {0.5, 0.1}], Graphics[{Arrowheads[0.3], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {1/(3 Sqrt[2]), 0}}]}]]`.

Comment: @Alx so the absolute length of the legend is $1/(3 Sqrt[2])$ and the relative length in respect to the vector field is 1, right?

Comment: @Alx what is the meaning of `VectorScale -> {0.5, 0.1}`? i just know the 1st argument is for the length of the arrow, and 2nd for the size of its arrowhead.

Comment: `VectorScale -> {0.5, 0.1}` means take largest arrow length to be 0.5 of the diagonal of plot range, 0.1 is scale of aroow head, see help on `VectorScale`. So, in my example in comments the largest arrow has "native" length of about 4.24, and reference arrow is about unit length.

Comment: Finally I came to conclusion that it is enough to add appropriate `VectorScale` to your original command: `VectorPlot[{y, -x}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, VectorScale -> {0.5, 0.15}, PlotLegends -> {"Ref. vector"}]`, Mathematica will do the rest.

Comment: @Alx it will be great if you have time to write your comment in a answer:)

Answer (score 1):

In help page on `VectorPlot` (and `VectorScale` as well) we can read: "By default, the vector length is scaled by the norm of the vector field". And from the documentation on `VectorScale` it has the following settings: `{unitlen, aratio, sfun}`, where "unitlen is given as a fraction of the diagonal of the overall bounding box", i.e. diagonal of plot range.

For the example in question, maximal arrow length is given by `Maximize[{Norm[{y, -x}], -3 <= x <= 3 && -3 <= y <= 3}, {x, y}] // First = 3 Sqrt[2]`, and the diagonal is `6 Sqrt[2]`. Hence if we want to see arrows having their "native" length (not scaled as Mathematica does by default) we need to apply appropriate scaling:

```
VectorPlot[{y, -x}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, VectorScale -> {0.5, 0.15},
PlotLegends -> {"Ref. vector"}]
```

[image]

If needed, number of arrows can be adjusted by `VectorPoints` option.

Comment: it is almost there! while it is still necessary to specify the arrow length of the legend to be unity (relative length), which is about $29\text{cm}/4.243=6.8$cm in absolute length.